# Custom folding in vim

Tags: vim, folding

in my .vimrc file, I have the follwing for custom folding javascript:

```
function! JavaScriptFold()
    setl foldmethod=syntax
    setl foldlevelstart=1
    syn region foldBraces start=/{/ end=/}/ transparent fold keepend extend

    function! FoldText()
        return substitute(getline(v:foldstart), '{.*', '{...}', '')
    endfunction
    setl foldtext=FoldText()
endfunction
au FileType javascript call JavaScriptFold()
au FileType javascript setl fen
```

It works great except for one thing: when folded, I have something like:

```
function hello(){...]-----------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is: how to get rid of the '----' that goes to the end of the line ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those characters are configured via the `fillchars` option, more specifically the `fold:` item of the `fillchars` option.

See `:help fillchars` for more info.

Comment: Thanks, how do you set the fillchars to 'null', 'blank' or space though ? It does not work when I put set fillchars=fold: and '' or ' ' or "" or " " or nothing in my .vimrc file

Comment: OK, got it working with: set fillchars=fold:\     Thanks again

Comment: Is set fillchars=fold:\ supposed to insert spaces? In my case it inserts "\" chars. How would you recommend to insert spaces?

Comment: @lyuba `set fillchars=fold:\ `, note the space after the backslash.